# How can I tell Drupal to add autocomplete=off to the login form

Tags: 7, users, forms

I'm under pressure to close out some issues from a Qualys scan. One issue flagged was

> 150112 Sensitive form field has not disabled autocomplete

Suggestions include adding `autocomplete="off"` to the username and password fields.

What would be the best practice way to achieve this?

Comment: Any luck with the No Autocomplete module? Are you experiencing other issues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems there is a module for this, [No Autocomplete](https://www.drupal.org/project/no_autocomplete).
As a sidenote (copied from the module's page:

> However, browsers and password managers and the like may very well not
>   respect the "autocomplete=off" attribute anyway. For example, Chrome
>   seems no longer to respect it and Lastpass ignores it by default.

Well, good luck with Qualys!

Comment: This looks promising but should I be scared off by the maintenance status? `Maintenance status: Seeking new maintainer. Development status: Maintenance fixes only`

Comment: I wouldn't be scared off, it's a tiny module, code-wise. Basically implements a form alter call to add an extra attribute: $form['#attributes']['autocomplete'] = 'off';

Comment: Did you get a chance to try this out?

Answer (score 1):

Use `hook_form_alter()` in a Drupal module:

```
function hook_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'user_login') {
    $form['pass']['#attributes']['autocomplete'] = 'off';
  }
}
```

Or use jQuery:

```
$('#edit-password').attr('autocomplete', 'off');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the attribute autocomplete='off' in **username** and **password** field of login page ***hook_form_alter()***

> Tested on Drupal 8 using **hook_form_alter()**

```
function hook_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'user_login_form') {
    $form['name']['#attributes']['autocomplete'] = 'off';
    $form['pass']['#attributes']['autocomplete'] = 'off';
  }
}
```